# How to convert a feGaussianBlur in SVG to a GaussianBlur effect in JavaFX?

Tags: java, svg, javafx

I am developing a library ([fxsvgimage](https://github.com/hervegirod/fxsvgimage)) which I use to show a SVG image in JavaFX. I am in the process of implementing the filters, and I have a question about the feGaussianBlur filter: Is it possible to convert reliably the `stdDeviation` parameter of the feGaussianBlur to the `radius` parameter of the GaussianBlur effect?

It seems that if I use the same value, I have a less blurry result in JavaFX than in SVG. For example, if I used this svg image:

```
<svg id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 156.364 147.239">
   <filter id="blur-shadow">
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" />
   </filter>   
   <style>.st0{fill:#DEDEDE;} .st1{fill:#3E295E;} .st2{fill:#FFFFFF;} .st3{fill:#429946;} .st4{fill:#F5EB30;}</style>
   <g filter="url(#blur-shadow)">
      <path class="st0" d="M149.18 34.834c-1.763-.91-4.134-.674-6.548.092-10.262 1.984-17.453 12.88-17.453 12.88s-8.05 1.577-12.96 2.358c10.125-3.084 24.564-9.366 21.786-22.434-1.268-5.97-8.025-6.787-13.127-6.463-6.048.384-11.54 2.974-16.475 6.358-2.884 1.978-4.76 4.745-7.837 6.526-.006 0-.013-.004-.02-.007-.462-3.778-1.33-10.193-2.626-17.04-2.042-10.79-20.226-2.148-25.08 1.727-4.855 3.876-13.762-2.594-22.162 1.525-4.757 2.333-3.22 10.92-.994 17.93-5.432-.777-10.88-1.32-16.39-.896-9.97.764-22.917 7.744-19.078 19.653l.1.304c3.498 10.17 19.07 13.142 28.376 13.244.173.003.345.003.518.002 2.115-.01 4.253-.143 6.395-.376-.064 1.434-.174 2.864-.58 4.266-.17.58-.307 1.142-.43 1.7-5.75-2.656-17.935-7.27-26.095-3.19-11 5.5-13.6 14.1-13.6 14.1s16.4 4.6 25 5.4c4.973.462 7.865-.48 9.425-1.356-4.118 3.43-14.906 13.63-14.826 26.254 0 0 18.656-6.395 25.547-18.147l.02.034c.977 2.207 2.092 4.147 3.903 6.133l.046.067c5.166 7.335 10.387 14.63 15.65 21.896 3.747 5.172 8.444 10.05 10.103 16.208 7.312-4.96 12.66-12.077 19.427-17.57 3.678-2.986 7.084-5.738 9.576-9.95 1.612-2.726 2.412-5.904 4.143-8.554 1.717-2.63 4.17-4.03 6.41-6.102 5.57-5.157 10.444-11.597 15.22-17.483 5.818-7.165 12.75-14.346 15.697-23.296 1.704-5.17 5.88-22.205-1.063-25.79z"/>
      <path class="st1" d="M48.514 44.41S37.29 20.786 45.692 16.666c8.4-4.12 17.308 2.35 22.163-1.525 4.854-3.875 23.04-12.518 25.08-1.726 2.042 10.792 3.024 20.522 3.024 20.522L48.513 44.41z"/>
      <path class="st1" d="M47.275 54.935c-1.746 1.45-4.162 5.82-5.43 2.113-.565-1.648.767-4.317 1.387-5.774 1.4-3.29 3.403-7.09 5.934-9.613 6.194-6.172 13.696-10.795 22.266-12.356 10.006-1.822 26.644-2.166 32.58 7.943-1.524 1.615-4.11 1.254-6.154 1.46-4.975.503-9.97 1.322-14.884 2.25-8.597 1.62-16.594 3.387-24.397 7.305-3.872 1.943-7.958 3.897-11.302 6.673z"/>
      <path class="st2" d="M53.065 44.975c-1.2.828-2.797 3.226-3.788 1.303-.44-.855.435-2.315.835-3.11.907-1.79 2.23-3.874 3.956-5.296 4.225-3.48 9.415-6.185 15.438-7.3 7.03-1.304 18.79-2.045 23.244 3.117-1.038.906-2.876.8-4.318.98-3.505.433-7.017 1.035-10.47 1.69-6.04 1.15-11.65 2.356-17.07 4.695-2.69 1.163-5.532 2.336-7.827 3.92z"/>
      <path class="st1" d="M9.23 53.353c-3.84-11.91 9.11-18.89 19.078-19.654 10.908-.84 21.567 2.104 32.34 3.17 4.47.444 8.984.638 13.46.19 7.78-.777 14.192-2.672 21.123-6.387 3.297-1.767 5.193-4.683 8.188-6.738 4.934-3.385 10.426-5.975 16.474-6.358 5.102-.324 11.858.494 13.127 6.463 2.895 13.62-12.918 19.873-23.05 22.812-4.49 1.302-8.826 3.556-13.305 5.083-9.54 3.253-20.404 4.374-29.536 8.43-8.87 3.938-19.136 6.495-28.905 6.538h-.518C28.4 66.8 12.83 63.827 9.332 53.657c-.036-.103-.07-.204-.102-.305z"/>
      <path class="st1" d="M71.954 40.42c-.674-.042-1.354-.04-2.042.027-11.94 1.147-21.738 8.624-24.74 20.434-.825 3.252-.19 6.657-1.134 9.91-1.077 3.713-1.236 6.87-.598 10.71.352 2.118.803 4.11 1.606 6.103.7 1.736 2.074 3.128 2.76 4.884 1.5 3.835 2.684 6.693 5.638 9.742 4.74 4.892 10.302 8.76 15.022 13.695 3.335 3.488 5.977 6.998 8.704 10.948 2.706 3.92 3.293.213 5.455-2.683 5.29-7.084 11.808-13.878 17.65-20.26 3.97-4.334 5.623-8.78 7.548-14.28 1.69-4.827 4.334-7.498 7.958-11.118 1.905-1.9 3.068-4.387 4.935-6.314 2.27-2.343 5.334-3.523 8.17-5.008 3.186-1.672 5.976-3.945 8.897-6.02 2.37-1.684 4.818-3.34 6.672-5.615 2.005-2.46 3.283-5.488 4.335-8.453.7-1.976 1.362-3.8 1.56-5.895.236-2.504.962-5.457-.3-7.825-1.31-2.46-4.706-2.65-7.112-2.373-10.947 1.257-18.747 13.084-18.747 13.084s-12.83 2.515-15.976 2.766c-4.583.366-4.358-1.523-6.45-4.828-2.28-3.598-7.27-3.285-10.918-2.476-3.666.814-6.038 3.18-9.987 2.59-2.996-.446-5.89-1.553-8.906-1.745z"/>
      <path class="st3" d="M123.417 52.3c1.146-.056 2.807 1.233 3.806 1.723.586.288.935.576 1.11.86 8.192-7.585 14.485-7.868 17.428-7.402 3.457-9.133 2.724-18.51-8.36-12.3-.086.05-.167.1-.252.15 1.014.693 1.382 2.736.806 4.926-.652 2.48-2.266 4.207-3.605 3.856-1.34-.353-1.895-2.65-1.244-5.13.126-.48.29-.93.478-1.345-8.02 5.9-10.273 12.767-10.273 12.767l-.377-4.027s-2.64 1.636-17.36 2.39c-4.575.236-10.343.916-14.362 3.27-3.872 2.267-6.598 6.035-10.702 7.994-3.466 1.655-6.385 2.345-10.102 1.143-3.986-1.29-7.342-3.79-11.708-1.483 4.056-4.517 13.172-5.255 18.77-4.347 2.604.423 5.304 1.292 7.724-.55 1.48-1.126 2.255-3.306 1.53-5.077-.877-2.14-2.595-1.842-4.498-2.308-4.683-1.145-8.73-3.78-13.757-2.79-6.58 1.296-12.49 5.987-16.57 11.148-2.968 3.75-3.617 7.155-4.643 11.6-1.206 5.222-2.315 10.52.07 15.622 4.53 9.687 19.877 15.348 31.577 6.416 0 0-2.137 4.403-8.93 6.29 0 0 18.493-1.005 27.676-6.542 9.184-5.535 15.852-14.34 15.852-14.34s-9.31 3.144-16.733 8.303c0 0 10.945-8.43 16.733-11.07 5.5-2.51 26.437-13.995 31.53-23.012-1.505-.32-4.764-.468-9.498 2.247-.357.205-.695.408-1.02.61.2.968.346 2.888.334 3.092-.062 1.07-.025 2.622-.69 3.537-1.738 2.393-2.19-2.408-4.02-3.47-3.062 2.443-5.996 4.883-13.618 7.72-.892.334-1.88.696-2.932 1.08-.09.97-.333 2.338-.382 2.497-.305.967-.632 2.396-1.452 3.08-2.058 1.713-1.5-2.353-2.708-3.922-3.93 1.426-8.346 3.027-12.63 4.627-.085.972-.338 2.405-.39 2.568-.303.965-.63 2.397-1.45 3.08-2.062 1.717-1.5-2.366-2.716-3.93-7.707 2.95-14.147 5.66-15.19 6.935-2.2 2.69.61 7.578-2.445 7.946-3.055.367-2.076-3.91-2.076-3.91.734-4.354 6.043-7.69 13.196-10.62.096-1.974-2.062-4.997.463-4.506 1.127.22 2.43 1.87 3.28 2.586.143.12.26.232.366.342 4.087-1.48 8.55-2.88 12.986-4.286.59-1.91-2.2-5.53.546-4.994 1.126.22 2.43 1.87 3.28 2.585.41.345.67.652.803.927.05-.015.1-.033.148-.05l-.082-.026c.19-.034.372-.087.56-.128 6.032-1.977 11.704-4.038 15.952-6.42 2.004-1.87-3.505-5.764-.225-5.93z"/>
      <path class="st4" d="M145.027 49.032c-.96-.203-2.637-.335-4.952.3-1.82.722-3.56 1.523-5.266 2.377-.098.058-.205.118-.3.178.2.968.346 2.888.334 3.092-.062 1.07-.025 2.622-.69 3.537-1.738 2.394-2.19-2.407-4.02-3.468-3.062 2.44-5.996 4.88-13.618 7.72-.892.332-1.88.694-2.932 1.08-.09.97-.333 2.336-.382 2.495-.305.967-.632 2.396-1.452 3.08-2.058 1.713-1.5-2.353-2.708-3.922-3.93 1.426-8.346 3.027-12.63 4.627-.085.972-.338 2.405-.39 2.568-.303.965-.63 2.397-1.45 3.08-2.062 1.717-1.5-2.366-2.716-3.93-7.707 2.95-14.147 5.66-15.19 6.935-2.2 2.69.61 7.578-2.445 7.946-1.977.235-2.263-1.47-2.22-2.705-3.035 2.15-10.978 3.108-8.62 9.695 5.107.593 10.632-.584 15.52-4.316 0 0-2.137 4.403-8.93 6.29 0 0 18.493-1.005 27.676-6.542 9.184-5.535 15.852-14.34 15.852-14.34s-9.31 3.144-16.733 8.303c0 0 10.945-8.43 16.733-11.07 5.5-2.512 26.437-13.997 31.53-23.013z"/>
      <path class="st2" d="M71.863 60.182c-1.31-.102-2.574-.5-3.575-1.312-.438-.356-1.08-1.02-.82-1.668.333-.825 1.657-.5 2.36-.453 1.41.095 1.7 1.408 2.802 2.23-.013-.01.592-1.752.752-1.886.663-.553 2.447-.12 3.22-.024 2.657.327 1.124 1.932-.383 2.483-1.305.478-2.863.746-4.357.63z"/>
      <path class="st3" d="M94.924 48.59c-1.24.477-4.767 3.145-4.713.465.032-1.52.863-3.392 1.647-4.678 1.226-2.01 4.08-2.646 6.23-1.812 1.508.585 3.855 2.724 2.29 4.277-1.38 1.367-3.71 1.078-5.453 1.75z"/>
      <path class="st1" d="M95.552 50.233s-6.52 4.645-17.504 14.202c-10.985 9.558-33.368 8.75-33.368 8.75s-5.484 8.964 8.35 28.602c5.165 7.335 10.386 14.63 15.65 21.896 3.747 5.17 8.444 10.05 10.103 16.208 7.313-4.96 12.66-12.077 19.428-17.57 3.68-2.986 7.085-5.738 9.577-9.95 1.612-2.726 2.412-5.904 4.143-8.554 1.717-2.63 4.17-4.03 6.41-6.1 5.57-5.158 10.444-11.598 15.222-17.484 5.817-7.166 12.75-14.347 15.696-23.297 1.703-5.172 5.88-22.207-1.064-25.792-4.33-2.232-12.323 2.38-15.63 5.027-2.678 2.144-7.06 8.546-10.396 9.16-.08.016-19.175 3.534-19.175 3.534l-5.76.017-1.68 1.353z"/>
      <path class="st4" d="M80.525 132.647c.222-.208-10.082-13.848-10.795-14.835-2.476-3.434-5.204-6.81-7.412-10.42-1.853-3.028-2.482-6.538-2.822-10.027-.152-1.567-1.383-5.96 1.498-5.4 1.773.345 4.04 2.61 5.49 3.657 1.21.875 2.514 1.53 3.743 2.344-1.168-1.793-2.148-3.726-3.118-5.643-1.65-3.253-3.84-6.12-5.716-9.22-.977-1.616-1.99-3.508-2.326-5.38-.546-3.047 1.793-2.39 4.074-2.853 6.515-1.323 13.243-3.57 18.336-8 3.14-2.733 6.323-5.42 9.56-8.04 3.6-2.915 8.1-7.232 13.102-7.996 4.782-.73 10.382-.843 15.318-1.193 2.22-.156 1.872 1.97 1.554 3.782-.558 3.174-2.4 6.314-4.425 8.79 3.055-2.076 5.637-5.315 7.287-8.583 3.7-7.333 9.74-14.243 17.604-17.4 8.268-3.313 5.57 11.09 4.946 15.31-1.446 9.758-9.358 20.89-16.818 26.996-4.71 3.855-9.554 7.53-14.576 10.95-4.25 2.892-8.547 6.166-12.982 8.736-3.37 1.953-6.965 3.546-10.617 4.975-4.036 1.58-14.33 6.128-16.863.135 1.38 3.833 1.752 6.657 6.44 7.9 3.542.937 7.864-.228 11.103-1.818 2.175-1.068 4.675-3.668 7.238-3.547 9.606.454-2.076 10.49-3.812 12.218-4.94 4.92-9.936 9.784-15.01 14.562z"/>
      <path class="st1" d="M46.837 74.102s-18.323-10.3-29.323-4.8c-11 5.5-13.6 14.1-13.6 14.1s16.4 4.6 25 5.4c8.6.8 10.998-2.6 10.998-2.6S23.415 98.1 23.514 113.698c0 0 22.56-7.73 27.23-21.815 4.67-14.084 3.67-18.284 3.67-18.284l-7.577.502z"/>
      <path class="st4" d="M27.375 108.64c1.26-4.986 4.15-9.452 7.5-13.29 1.288-1.476 2.782-2.74 4.098-4.176 1.495-1.632 3.85-2.617 4.864-4.674.488-.99.875-2.07 1.2-3.125.354-1.15 1.12-2.497 1.16-3.66-2.724.252-5.423.586-8.212.586-3.635 0-7.423-.046-10.97-.026 4.964 1.398 10.194 1.794 15.163 3.02-1.185.763-2.606 1.063-3.966 1.406-2.116.533-4.606.993-6.785.993-.7 0-1.445-.036-2.215-.108-5.767-.536-15.407-2.91-20.688-4.29 1.615-2.566 4.746-6.26 10.434-9.105 1.692-.847 3.793-1.275 6.245-1.275 9.228 0 19.946 5.942 20.053 6.003l.835.468 5.027-.33c-.297 2.514-1.143 6.88-3.44 13.813-2.687 8.106-13.12 14.453-20.302 17.77z"/>      
   </g>

</svg>
```

With a `stdDeviation` of 3, I have this in SVG:

[image]

And this in JavaFX by using the same value for the `radius`:

[image]

Comment: See [*Gaussian Blur—Standard Deviation, Radius and Kernel Size*](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/10057).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting your radius to `2 * stdDeviation`.  That's what the relationship between the two generally is. Hopefully JavaFX also follows that rule.

Comment: thanks, it's much better!